# Does thread block on synclock

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, silverlight

I've got the following code in a vb.net module called from Silverlight. It basically assigns unique ids on a per-thread basis.

```
Public Module IdManager

Private _threadTrackingIds As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
Private _lockObject As New Object

Public Function GetNext() As String
    Dim threadId = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
    Dim g As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    SyncLock _lockObject
        _threadTrackingIds(threadId) = g
    End SyncLock
    Return g
End Function

Public ReadOnly Property CurrentTrackingID As String
    Get
        Dim threadId = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
        Dim idToReturn As String = String.Empty
        SyncLock _lockObject
            If (_threadTrackingIds.ContainsKey(threadId)) Then
                idToReturn = _threadTrackingIds(threadId)
            End If
        End SyncLock
        Return idToReturn
    End Get
End Property

End Module
```

The GetNext() returns a string, but in most cases I am just calling it without checking the return value (that is, just calling IdManager.GetNext() without assigning it to a variable) because I don't need the value until later (other methods sometimes) so I just call CurrentTrackingId when I need it.

However, I have multiple threads calling this (hence the synclock) so my question is: will my calling code for IdManager.GetNext() block on the call if it does not get the lock, or will it carry on until it needs to block? That is, I'm wondering if not assigning the string value to a variable (i.e. z = IdManager.GetNext()), and then perhaps using that variable, would make the caller ignore the fact that it did not get the lock. If it doesn't block on it, then would the thread carry on to the rest of the instructions without possibly setting the CurrentTrackingID yet?

Comment: `SyncLock` does not block the thread, it keeps other things from accessing that object. If you don't assign the value to anything, how does it magically become available on the `CurrentTrackingId` object?

Comment: @OneFineDay when I say I don't assign it to anything I mean I don't assign the value returned from GetNext() to a local variable in my calling code. GetNext() itself assigns the value to a dictionary in the module, so instead of grabbing the value returned from GetNext() I can get it from CurrentTrackingID. I'm just wondering if is possible that a thread may not have a value returned in CurrentTrackingId because they could not get the lock on GetNext() previously. Is this any clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, SyncLock provides synchronization by allowing only one thread to enter the protected code.  Any other thread that tries to enter at the *exact* same time will be blocked until the lock is released.

The odds that this will actually happen are very low.  But not zero.  You are holding the lock for a very short time, Dictionary is quite efficient and takes but a small fraction of a microsecond.  You'd have to call these methods hundreds of thousands of times per second to notice any contention.

Nothing to worry about.  You could fall back to ConcurrentDictionary if absolutely necessary, it uses a finer-grained lock and is friendlier since you don't have to explicitly use SyncLock.